# Krita brush path

Tags: vector, brush, krita

I tried everything I could but I just can't figure out how to get Krita to apply a pixel brush along a vector path. I have read things that imply it should be possible and it seems obvious but I just can't figure out how/

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing you can do to this is convert a vector path to a pixel brush stroke.

For my test, I used the calligraphy tool to make a little squiggle on the canvas. This creates a vector path on a vector layer.

From there go to the main menu Edit > Stroke Selected Shape. I think that option should be there on any Krita 4.x version.

This will apply a pixel brush stroke along a vector path. The result will be on a paint layer though, so you can't just modify the vector path later and expect the pixel data to update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> Click when you are done creating path.

Answer (score 0):

> Krita currently has no functionality to use brush as stroke for vector objects. And aparently never had (tested on 3.3 and 4.0).

Your confusion may come from the **FreeHand Path Tool** [image], specifically from the outline setting on it, that allow brush as one of them because it can be used on normal layers too:

[image]